# Android Firebase Database checking if user is in specific group

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 5 different user types I want to check if a user is in one of the 4 special user types and change the menu ui based on that. This is what I found by my self but it doesn't work.

```
mDatabase.child("staff").orderByChild(mAuth.getUid()).equalTo("true").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String staffType = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                if (staffType == "servers"){
                    mTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuUser)));
                }
            }
```

my firebase database

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (staffType == "servers"){
mTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuUser)));
}
```

into this:

```
if (staffType.equals("servers")){
mTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuUser)));
}
```

from the docs:

> `public boolean equals(Object anObject)`
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: this didn't fix it it still will return false on the check

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer highlights one problem, but there's one more thing wrong with your code.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So the code in your `onDataChange` needs to handle this potentially multiple children by looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String staffType = userSnapshot.getKey();
    if (staffType.equals("servers")){
        mTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuUser)));
    }
}
```

While the check may work with these changes, it will never be efficient at scale since you need to look at too much data to find the user you want. Your current data structure allows you to efficiently look up all users for a given role. It does not allow efficient look up for the role for a specific user though. For that, you should add an additional data structure with precisely that information: the role for each UID. So something like:

```
user-roles
  "22yXY813cW...": "server"
  "uid2": "cook"
```

With this additional structure, you can efficiently look up the role for a user without a query:

```
mDatabase.child("user-roles").child(mAuth.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String staffType = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        if (staffType.equals("servers")){
            mTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuUser)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code below doesn't work because I get the key and thats the UID and not the value

Comment: You're querying under `mDatabase.child("staff")`, so the results you get back are the direct children of `staff`. So `getKey()` is `admins`, `server`, etc.

Comment: I cant let it work I am trying things for hours are you sure this is correct https://pastebin.com/9njWn00q the textvield is empty on the fragment so nothing seem to happen

Comment: it should be working right but it doesn't I also checked the uid and they are the same but still the textvield is empty it doesn't return the child from staff